# How do i solve implementation not found error?

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to programming and android studio. I keep running into this error:

Error Message:

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I found that someone ran into the same problem about some odd 2 years ago, but the solutions seem to be outdated

I am currently using Android studio 3.5.3

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Your other dependencies...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
}
```

It keeps pointing this part of the code out

it would be great if someone could help me solve this.

Comment: Which gradle version are you using?